# Issue with column's width when server-side processing is enable

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I am using server-side processing with Ajax and JSON. When the rows are returned it's perfect  but if i resize the page it's broken.
[image: issue]

Answer (score -1):

The easy fix is set 100% width for table header

```
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner {width:100% !important;}
 table.table {width:100% !important;}
```

[image]

Comment: why did you post the question to answer, if you know the fix?

Comment: well better to post this at those posts then. that would be much better.

Comment: Agree with @Jai, and to be more specific - this "fix" does not explain why the alleged dataTables misbehaviour occur (_if_ it actually _is_ a dataTables issue and not a error 40 or browser settings issue, like apple scrollbars etc) or why it should solve the problem setting the width to 100%. As a long time user of dataTables it does not sound completely logic, more like a XY problem / solution, but could of course be wrong. At least it would be nice to see a fiddle that reproduces the problem and PoC's the fix.

Comment: Try add  ` "autoWidth": false` when inicializate your datatable